# Can I use MySQL with JS/NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js

I used to add MySQL/MySQLi DB with PHP and MongoDB in Node js. I can use MongoDB with PHP also. What is the best way to use MySQL/MySQLi with  JS/node.js?
any video tutorial will be helpful for me.

Comment: node.js package provider `npm` provides various modules such as `mysql` and `mysql2` to work with mysql database in node.js

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use with NodeJs, I have no video tutorial but knex will help you

http://knexjs.org

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I use MariaDB perfectly. No problems.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).